# Unable to work with SQL Server CE 4.0

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce-4

I try to work with a SQL Server CE 4.0 database with my simple console app but it is not working on one of my machine.

OS: Windows Server 2003 Enterprise x64 Edition with Service Pack 2

I have also installed Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 and used its dll (`System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll`) but every time I got following error

> Unable to load the native components of SQL Server C
>   ADO.NET provider of version 8080. Install the correc
>   act. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details.

Here is my code

```
 try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Started");

             var sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=c:\\tde\\22\\22.tde;password='sanjayraj';mode=Read Write;max database size=4091;temp file max size=4091";
            _connection = new SqlCeConnection(sqlConnectionString);
            _connection.Open();

            var sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM InfoStores WHERE Location = 'Source'";

            IDbCommand newCommand = new SqlCeCommand
            {
                CommandText = sqlStatement,
                Connection = _connection,
                CommandType = CommandType.Text
            };

            using (IDataReader reader = newCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error Occured");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

You a referenceing the wrong version of System.data.SqlServerCe.dll, use the one in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Desktop folder